# Cast string data type to Int in SQL QUery for MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, casting

I am trying to write a query in access that will pull results that are
in the database in a text
Acually,I have RECEIPTNO Column whose datatype is TEXT in Table Membership, & I want to pull all the results from RECEIPTNO column where RECEIPTNO is BETWEEN 1 AND 10

And I tried Below Code.

```
SELECT Cint(RECEIPTNO) FROM MEMBERSHIP where Cint(RECEIPTNO) BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

**Result is: Overflow ,**
Any Idea?

Comment: Are you confusing the Jet/ACE/Access Integer data type with SQL Server Integer? The corresponding Jet/ACE/Access data type is Long Integer, so CLng() might work. But @Remou's suggestion of Val() avoids the problem entirely.

Answer (score 5):

Do you want:

```
SELECT RECEIPTNO FROM MEMBERSHIP
WHERE Val(RECEIPTNO) BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Answer (score 3):

Ohhh I got the answer, & it's working

& the Query Like

```
SELECT Cint(RECEIPTNO) FROM MEMBERSHIP where RECEIPTNO BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Comment: sorry Above query not working,Coz For Above query Working Only When RECEIPTNO Column DataType Must be Number.But I want Query When RECEIPTNO Datatype is TEXT

PleaseHelp

Comment: `CInt` doesn't work on strings, only on values. Use `Val` instead - see Fionnuala's answer!

Answer (score 2):

This gives you what you want. ss

```
SELECT RECEIPTNO FROM MEMBERSHIP
WHERE Val(RECEIPTNO & "") BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

Others using Val(RECEIPTNO) will only TRY to work somehow half-heartedly where it does beacuse the system doesn not recognise the RECEIPTNO as text and so, it is funny to it to see you passing a number instead of a string. However, to convince the system that the format is actually a number, concatenate it with an empty string which I have done.